# How to properly use Javascript objects for a game perk system?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, game-development

I am currently looking to build a text/choice-based game using simple JS, CSS, HTML.

I am to use a character object, and then allow users to choose which perks they would like.

The perks are...

1. luckPerk - increase gold dropped by enemies and rewards for choosing the right outcome.
2. thickSkinPerk - reduces damage by 10% throughout the game.
3. List item - greaserPerk - makes the greaser faction of the game like you, meaning if a greaser card appears, the options will be either all good and greaser based vendors will sell items cheaper.
4. roachManPerk - removes all radiation throughout the game.

I am thinking something like this would work...

```
let character = {
    name: "Survior",
    health: 100,
    maxHP: 100,
    radiation: 0,
    repuation: 50,
    cash: 25,
    radiated: false,
    radiationLevel: 0,
    hatedByGreaser: false,
    hatedByRebels: true,
    hatedBySecurity: false,
    lovedByGreaser: false,
    lovedByRebels: false,
    lovedBySecurity: false,
    lucky: false,
    luckyRate: 0,
    thickSkin: false,
    thickSkinRate: 0,
    greaser: false,
    roachMan: false,
    roachManRate: 0,
}
```

EDIT: I think I came up with a good idea while waiting for a response. Above I added new vars `luckyRate: 0`, `thickSkinRate: 0` , and `roachManRate: 0`...

I added this because what I am now thinking of doing is checking if the perks are selected, and if they are, change the rates. So if `roachManPerk` becomes true after I check the checkboxes ( the code for this is below ), I can then change the `roachManRate` to `1`, which I can then use in my program to remove all damage taken by radiaition by doing something like  `radDamage - ( radDamage * roachManRate )`.

At the beginning of the game, the user should be able to choose 2 of these perks at the beginning of the game, which will change the boolean to true.

here is the code for this...

```js
function chosePerks(){
const luckyCheck = document.getElementById("luckyCheck").checked;
const thickSkinCheck = document.getElementById("thickSkinCheck").checked;
const greaserCheck = document.getElementById("greaserCheck").checked;
const roachManCheck = document.getElementById("roachManCheck").checked;

if(luckyCheck == true) {
    character.lucky == true;
// This means 20%, which I wil add to all functions that add money, giving 20% more money
    character.luckRate = .2;
}
if(thickSkinCheck == true) {
    character.thickSkin == true;
    // This means 30%, which I wil add to all functions that add damage, removing 30% of the damage
     character.thichSkinRate = .3;
} 
if(greaserCheck == true) {
    character.greaser == true;
} 
if(roachManCheck == true) {
    character.roachMan == true;
    // This means 100%, which I wil add to all functions that add radiation damage, removing 100% of the damage
     character.roachManRate = 1;
} 

}
```

However, I am confused on how I can properly set this up better, because I am starting to realize that If the user ( for example ) chooses the roachManPerk ( no radiation ), I would have to go into each "choice" and say something like `if(roachManPerk != true){ then add radiation )`, which seems like it would get repetitive. Each game choice would have to check if a perk is `true` or `false`

Let's take the greaserPerk for example. Is there a way to see if a choice is being `authored` ( aka, an NPC in choice-based RPG ) by a greaser, and if so, and assuming the user has the greaserPerk, change the options, or simply disable some?

Here is how I plan on going about making the questions list, or rather, the "choices" for the game. If a specific choice is selected, that next text node is loaded.

```
const textNodes = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: "Do you want to help this person?",
        options: [
           {
            text: "Yes",
            nextText: 2
           },
           {
            text: "No",
            nextText: 2
           },
        ],
        faction: "Greaser"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: "It was a trap, do you run or kill them?",
        options: [
           {
            text: "Run",
            nextText: 3
           },
           {
            text: "Kill",
            nextText: 5
           },
        ],
        faction: "Greaser"
    }
]
```

I am not sure if I am approaching this correctly and would appreciate guidance on this.

EDIT: Here is my code for running a function whenever a choice is picked. I cannot call the function for some reason.

```js
{
        id: 2,
        text: "It was a trap, do you run or kill them?",
        options: [
           {
            text: "Run",
            nextText: 3,
            damage: 0,
           },
           {
            text: "Kill",
            nextText: 5,
            damage: 8,
            moneyDrop: 20,
            radiationDamage: 2,
            function: function update(){
            character.health -= this.damage;
            character.cash += this.moneyDrop;
            character.radiationLevel += this.radiationDamage;
            if(this.radiationDamage >= 1){
                addRadiatedStatus();
            }
            console.log("character HP" + " " +  character.health);
            console.log("moneyDrop " + " " +  this.moneyDrop);
            console.log("character cash" + " " +  character.cash);
            console.log("radiation level" + " " +  character.radiationLevel);
            console.log("character Raditated?" + " " +  character.radiated);
            },
           }
        ],
        faction: "Greaser"
    }
```

Comment: Yea, that seems like it would work. What trouble are you having with implementing it?

Comment: Okay so i moved forwards and I am having trouble with adding a function to a question and calling it. I added a function key pair to my question ID: 2 like `logic: function update(){ do stuff }` , but I am not sure how to call it. Saying `textNodes[1].logic` doesn't work.

Comment: To call a function, you need parentheses. `textNodes[1].logic()`.

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it didn’t work. Let me send you the error in my next comment @EKW

Comment: @EKW whenever I try `textNodes[1].update()` I get the error ‘... is not a function`. I added my code to the bottom of the post.

Comment: I forgot I changed logic() to update(), but it still doesn't work. I also know that in ES6 I don't need to say `function` , but I get errors when removing the function key word.

Comment: textNodes[1].options[1].function(); worked and fixed. Closed